# Wrong results when working with numpy integers

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

when working with python in google colab some behavior occures which i'm trying to understand.

I have the following function

```
def poisson(x,_lambda_):
  return (math.exp(-_lambda_) * _lambda_ ** x) / math.factorial(x)
```

When i use this function with native python integers i everything seems fine

```
poisson(70,mylambda)
```

-> 0.04474020748359926

but when i use numpy integers the result is wrong

```
poisson(np.int64(70),mylambda)
```

-> -1.445513513413155e-113

Could someone explain, what i am doing wrong here ?
As far as i understood the difference from native integer to numpy integer is just the length and shouldn't result in such a mess.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: sry have forgotten mylambda = 73

Comment: "As far as i understood the difference from native integer to numpy integer is just the length" - how many bits do you think it takes to represent `_lambda_ ** x`?

Comment: Yes many thanks... 
Thought about integer overflow before, but in my head i estimated it wrong ("*" not "**")...

A little bit surprising that numpy doesn't warn you when you exceed datatype limit, but very valuable to learn that.

Comment: FWIW this might help avoiding some overflows: `math.exp(x * math.log(_lambda_) - _lambda_) / math.factorial(x)`. Getting rid of the factorial and using some sort of series might help further

Comment: Side-note: Please don't put missing information into comments. You can just edit your question

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, nothing should be different between the two except for the length of the datatype.

In my testing, I found that `poisson(70,mylambda)` and `poisson(np.int64(70),mylambda)` both returned the same value when I set `mylambda` to `5.5`, where the return value was `2.2822519060129615e-51`

I wonder if maybe the way that you're defining/ calculating `mylambda` could be the issue? Perhaps you could give a bit more context behind how these are being called and how their parameters are calculated! Maybe then it'll be a bit more clear what is wrong. :)